# $injector:nomod with Karma + Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am struggling with running a basic UT with Karma and Jasmine. It looks like Karma/Jasmine is not able to pick up the module while running the tests. When running `npm start`, I do not get the same error.

I am getting the below error:

```
Chrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
      {
        "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'UTAppV2' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.4/$injector/nomod?p0=UTAppV2",
        "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'UTAppV2' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.4/$injector/nomod?p0=UTAppV2"
      }
Chrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 ERROR (0.01 secs / 0.001 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

My Karma.conf.js file

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/*.spec.js',
      'app/*.component.js',
      'app/*.module.js',
      'app.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity,
  })
}
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "uttestingv2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "UT Testing V2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1"
  },
  "author": "Luke",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.4",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.7.4",
    "jasmine": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

Test.spec.js file

```
describe('Basic Test', function () {
    beforeEach(module('UTAppV2'));
    it('has a dummy spec to test', function () {
        expect(4).toBe(4);
    });
});
```

App.js

```
angular.module('UTAppV2', []);
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="UTAppV2">

   <head>
      <script src = "node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div>
        <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

How do I resolve the below error when running the tests:

> Module 'UTAppV2' is not available!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a combination of objects not being cleared in memory as well as the module being defined after the component in the Karma config file.